# How to live edit a class/functional component on Storybook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, sass, storybook

Hello i m using `storybook/react` library to create stories of my components.

So far so good, I followed the tutorial on `https://www.learnstorybook.com/react/en/get-started` and i have add stories on the left side of the screen with the `add` command, like so:

`add('archived', () => <Task task={{ ...task, state: 'TASK_ARCHIVED' }} {...actions} /> );`

The `Task` component is a functional component.

I 'm also using the `storybook-addon-react-live-edit` `storybook addon`, from https://github.com/vertexbz/storybook-addon-react-live-edit for having live edit on the stories, like so:
[image]

The code for the above example is this:

`` 
stories.addDecorator(withLiveEditScope({ React, Test }));

stories.add('simple JSX', withLiveEdit(`return <div>hello there!!</div>`, {color: 'red'}))`

This code is simple because i just show jsx code.

### Problem

I want to live edit a `functional` or `class component`, from another file but the functions `withLiveEdit(source[, scope])` and `addLiveSource(name, source[, scope])`, accept only string as the `source`.

So if i add the story like so: **stories.addLiveSource('demo', `return ${Test}`);**

`Test` is a separate `Test.js` file:

const Test = `class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, world!!</h1>;
  }
}`

`export default Test;`

Results is, it shows the code on 'live tab', but its not actually rendered on the top window.

[image]

**So my question is, how can i import class or functional components on addLiveSource()/withLiveEdit()**

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using webpack too? Have you looked at the React Hot Module reloading packages? 
npm install --save-dev express webpack-dev-middleware webpack-hot-middleware

Comment: I m using CRA boilerplate, it has webpack. But If you see the example on the github, its just a simple JSX which is imported into the function as String.I m using hot reloding.The first screenshot works ok, i can make live Edits.

Answer (score 1):

I hit the same issue, you can do this:

```
storiesOf(group, module)
  .addDecorator(withLiveEditScope({ React, SomeFunctionComponent, StyledHeader }))
  .addLiveSource("title", `<SomeFunctionComponent><StyledHeader>hello</StyledHeader></SomeFunctionComponent>`);
```

Basically anything you use inside the template literal in `addLiveSource` which would need an import you need to add to `withLiveEditScope`.
The only drawback is you have to write it all inside the template literal (P.S. if you solve that limitation please let me know!)